# Fetching data in API Explorer for Azure Application Insights REST API returns null (status 200)

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using Application ID and API keys for our Application Insights instance in API Explorer but getting null responses. Do I need to change any security settings on our App Insights instance to be able to fetch results??

Here is what I get below. The keys are correct (otherwise status would not be 200).

HTTP/1.1 200
content-length: 109
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
"value": {
"start": "2020-11-20T07:17:23.540Z",
"end": "2020-11-20T19:17:23.540Z",
"requests/count": {
"sum": null
}
}
}

Comment: what's the timestamp you're using in the query? and do you really check there're data in this timestamp in azure portal?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the response status is 200, it means that the query is ok.

As per Ivan mentioned in the comment, you should check the timestamp specified in the query. Maybe there are no data just in the specified timestamp.